# AngularJs conditionally assigning a value to a scoped variable

Tags: angularjs

Ok so let me prefix this by saying I am sure I am doing this in an ass backwards way but I cannot for the life of me see how this should be done.

I have the following scope variable :

```
  $scope.house.petsModel = function(){
    if(!PetService.isCreate()){
        return CommonService.getPetsById($scope.petModel.id, $scope.availablePets);
    }
    else{return {}}
}
```

The idea here is to conditionally set my `house.petsModel` depending on whether I am creating a new pet or editing an existing pet such that I can reuse the same view.

The error I get is as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'petsModel' of true
at new <anonymous> (add-pet.js:26)
at invoke (angular.js:4476)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4484)
at angular.js:9142
at resolveSuccess (ui-bootstrap.js:4138)
at processQueue (angular.js:14678)
at angular.js:14694
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15922)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15733)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16030)
```

I am so confused as to why it thinks I should not be able to write a value to my petsModel scoped variable.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

as requested: this is how I am declaring house

```
$scope.house = HouseService.getHouse();
```

Comment: How did you define $scope.house? Could you show some relevant codes?

Comment: Did `CommonService.getPetsById` return a promise?

Comment: at present getPetsById does not return a promise, just static json

Comment: @gzc as requested i have added how i am declaring house

Comment: I want to see code in getHouse() which eventually define `house`.

Comment: You should post adequate code for others to figure out what the problem could be. I don't think you would get a constructive answer when you say your object has an error without showing what the object is.

Comment: all that method is is controller setting a service variable of json that was defined in a previous view, it is then set in that variable and grabbed by the controller we are talking about now.

code is essentially HouseService.setHouse(houseJson); followed by what you see above.

Comment: @CharlieH the object the error is reporting in question is the object i have posted above, the only time i ever get the error is when i conditionally try to assign the variable 'petsModal' : if I assign it what needs to be assigned for the edit functionality it works as expected. If i try to assign it conditionally depending on whether it is a create or a edit i get the error above.

Comment: see my answer, was a wild goose chase, cheers for the input.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like chrome was actually sending me on a wild goose chase, the error had exactly zero to do with what the problem was which turned out to be a dependant variable being set in edit but not create.

firefox had a meaningful error where as chrome did not O.o